# Exterior gas tank

Tags: chevrolet, fuel-system, silverado

So I have a 2004 Chevy Silverado 1500 I do a lot of driving and want to put a gas tank in the bed, then tap it into the gas tank under the truck. What would be the best way to do that? Would I have to run another gas line. Would I need to run another pump for the tank in the bed. What are some recommendations on tanks?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! I took a look at what was available for the 2004, thinking they might have been available with an auxiliary fuel tank. I know my when I was a kid, my Dad's GMC pickup had the availability. It really comes down to safety. Tapping into something in the bed of your truck might not be the best choice. There is a 35 gallon tank available for the long bed trucks, but I doubt if it would fit on a short bed, if that's what you have.

Comment: Consider how you fill both tanks: do you fill both individually? Do you plumb them so they fill sequentially - and empty sequentially? Do you provide a changeover switch to switch when the original tank is low? A possible disadvantge is that you may not have a level indicator on the second tank... All these solutions have been applied, but it depends on how you want it to work...

Comment: Another thought with having one tank higher than the other is, you cannot just have a feed line, because it would siphon off into the lower tank when filled, which would mean it would end up all over the ground. You'd need to have a positive lock which would keep it from draining. This might be able to be done through a pump, but you'd have to double check to ensure it wouldn't allow fuel passage when not running. If that didn't work, you'd have to rig some kind of solenoid shutoff valve, which would only open if the pump was on.

Comment: First, consider the legal implications. There are almost certainly safety requirements for gas tanks. Breaking the rules might be fine - until you are involved in an accident, your insurance won't pay out on an illegally modified car, and the police prosecute for no insurance cover (and anything else they can think of, to maximize the return on their time spent doing the paperwork!).